# StatusBar with individual color

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Is there any way to set the Color of the statusBar to an individual color. So that the icons are in blue or in green. I don´t want to change the Background color, only change color of the icons in the statusBar. I only found to set the statusBar to Default, LightContent, BlackTranslucentm BlackOpaque. Is there a way to use the own color?

Comment: Do you wants to change status bar icons color?

Answer (score 0):

Set the UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance to YES in the .plist file.
in appdelegate

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

do this

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent animated:YES];
```

in ios availble style's are

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UIStatusBarStyle) {
    UIStatusBarStyleDefault                                     = 0, // Dark content, for use on light backgrounds
    UIStatusBarStyleLightContent     NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0) = 1, // Light content, for use on dark backgrounds

    UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent NS_ENUM_DEPRECATED_IOS(2_0, 7_0, "Use UIStatusBarStyleLightContent") = 1,
    UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque      NS_ENUM_DEPRECATED_IOS(2_0, 7_0, "Use UIStatusBarStyleLightContent") = 2,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't change the status bar color to anything else than `Default, LightContent, BlackTranslucent and BlackOpaque`. Apple doesn't offer us any method for this and most likely won't.